# Insert tag html into MYSQL using PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert tag html (embed from youtube into Mysql) using Codeigniter like

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7jE-OcfMU2Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But in the value in the table like

```
&lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7jE-OcfMU2Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>&lt;/iframe>
```

What sholud I do to solve it?

This is my controller, but it's still not work properly

```
$emb=str_replace('&lt;', '<', $this->input->post('embed'));
data = array(
      'content' => $this->input->post('judul'),
      'embed' => $emb,
      'category' => 'video',
);            
$this->m_admin_tb_website->update_data('video', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using htmlspecialchars_decode function?

Try this code:

```
$emb = htmlspecialchars_decode($this->input->post('embed'));
```

It works fine for me when I need to do the same you want.